# Duplicating Agisoft Metashape Projects

Tags: alignment, ground-control, agisoft-photoscan, rtkgps+

I am currently processing data for my Master's thesis and I need to process the same datasets many times with small changes each time. For example:

- Not using GCPs
- Using 9 GCPs
- Using 1 GCP
- Using RTK
- Using NTRIP
  I will be using Agisoft Metashape to process the images.

Now, I have created a project and have the images aligned. How can I duplicate the project with aligned images, so that it does not have to be executed every time (alignment again).

I am aware of the duplicate chunk option, but I do not think is ideal for what I am trying to accomplish.